# Reveal Js save description-variable just once for all products on a magento website

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento-1.7, reveal.js

On a product website, I am trying to show the description of every product in a popup with the help of Reveal JS.

```
       <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
             <h1>Beschreibung</h1>
             <p style="margin-top: 20px;">

             <?php
                        $_product = $item->getProduct();
                        $pid = $_product->getId();
                        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
                        /* getting some attributes */


                         echo $beschreibung = $product->getData('beschreibung'); 

                        ?>


             </p>
             <a class="close-reveal-modal">Schließen</a>
        </div>

        <h6><a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Beschreibung</a></h6>
```

Now when I put more products in the cart and go to the checkout (where the description has to be shown) I only get the description of the first product for all products!

For example: if I have `item1`, `item2`, `item3` in the cart. 
I get description1 for `item1`, `item2` and `item3`.

Has anyone an idea how can I solve this ?? thank you.

Comment: what file are you putting this code in?

Comment: Hi and thank you for helping me! I am putting this code in the : Summary.phtml. 
I can get the description without any problem but when i add more items it shows only one and the same Description for all products. it just save the description once!

Comment: no problem, could you please provide the full path of the file, from app/

Comment: app/frontend/base/default/template/onestepcheckout/summary.phtml

Comment: Is there a way to programm a loop in reveal so i can save the variable eveytime i click on description?